# failing to update private fields in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, field

I have a private field in the code behind file of Asp.net page that I'm trying to reset but for some reason it doesn't update. this is the field

```
private double interest = 0;
```

I then update this field in this method:

```
protected void DropDownListBanks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MajesticEntities majesticentities = new MajesticEntities();
    var query2 = from bank in
                        majesticentities.Banks
                 where bank.Name == DropDownListBanks.SelectedValue
                 select bank.Interest;

    interest =  query2.Single().Value;
 //   Label5.Text = interest.ToString();
    //   Label5.Text = fees.ToString() + "welcome";
}
```

When I try to use the field again in a code initiated by a button click I get the original value (0)

Can anyone please explain why this is happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to save them in an hidden field , textbox , label or in a view state.

```
ViewState["VSinterest"] = interest;
```

Then the value will be saved after postback
"after postback " private double interest = 0; " = 0"

Then if you need te value you take it from where you saved it and convert it to what it needs to be

Comment: I thought private fields work here the same way as in C# application. They clearly don't